# Is it grammatically correct to use "by + do-ing (A) + do-ing (B) + do-ing (C)"?

Tags: grammar

I have been wondering if in my writing the following sentence is grammatically correct:

> *We accomplish this by first **gathering** all relevant news stories, then **picking out** those that mention "bankruptcy", and finally **keeping** only the ones released by renowned media.*

I think it's ok to say **by + do-ing** but not sure if is fine to use **by + do-ing (A) + do-ing (B) + do-ing (C)** (can not recall any example). Can anyone tell if this sounds correct? Many thanks!

Comment: It sounds correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I fixed my wardrobe issue by **washing**, **drying**, and **folding** my laundry.

There is nothing wrong with using any number of such verbs, either directly next to each other (as here) or simply within the same sentence at some point (as in your case).

In fact, if you start off with one verb being in this form, then it's likely you'll want to use the same form for all of them.

This, for example, would *not* be considered appropriate:

> We accomplish this by first **gathering** all relevant news stories, then **picking out** those that mention "bankruptcy", and finally ***keep*** only the ones released by renowned media.